# prototype this selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

If I'm using the following function :

```
clusters.prototype.shop_iqns_selected_class = function() {
    if(this.viewport_width < 980) {
        $(this.iqns_class).each(function() {
            $(this.iqn).on('click', function() {
                if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

To add a property to the clusters function, I know that using `this.viewport_width` I'm referring to the parent function where I have `this.viewport_width` defined, but when I'm using the jQuery selector `$(this)`, am I referring to the parent of the `$.on()` function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, `this` is defined entirely by *how a function is called*. jQuery's `each` function calls the iterator function you give it in a way that sets `this` to each element value, so within that iterator function, `this` no longer refers to what it referred to in the rest of that code.

This is easily fixed with a variable in the closure's context:

```
clusters.prototype.shop_iqns_selected_class = function() {
    var self = this; // <=== The variable
    if(this.viewport_width < 980) {
        $(this.iqns_class).each(function() {
            // Do this *once*, you don't want to call $() repeatedly
            var $elm = $(this);

            // v---- using `self` to refer to the instance
            $(self.iqn).on('click', function() {
                // v---- using $elm
                if($elm.hasClass('selected')) {
                    $elm.removeClass('selected');
                } else {
                    $elm.addClass('selected');
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

There I've continued to use `this` to refer to each DOM element, but you could accept the arguments to the iterator function so there's no ambiguity:

```
clusters.prototype.shop_iqns_selected_class = function() {
    var self = this; // <=== The variable
    if(this.viewport_width < 980) {
        // Accepting the args -----------v -----v
        $(this.iqns_class).each(function(index, elm) {
            // Do this *once*, you don't want to call $() repeatedly
            var $elm = $(elm);

            // v---- using `self` to refer to the instance
            $(self.iqn).on('click', function() {
                // v---- using $elm
                if($elm.hasClass('selected')) {
                    $elm.removeClass('selected');
                } else {
                    $elm.addClass('selected');
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

More reading *(posts in my blog about `this` in JavaScript)*:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Comment: One question though, will this function ( the above ) run automatically when instantiating the `cluster` function ? Because I would like that to happen if the `if()` statement is meet.

Comment: @Roland: Glad that helped. When you do `var c = new cluster();`, the object you get back will be backed by the `cluster.prototype` object. To call the `shop_iqns_selected_class` function, you'd do `c.shop_iqns_selected_class();` (Side note: The overwhelming convention in JS is to use initially-capped names for constructor functions, e.g. `Cluster` rather than `cluster`.)

Comment: I see, I'm testing for now, that's why the vars may not make any sense at all. But there's no way to make that function run without me having to initiate it separately ?

Comment: @Roland: You can put `this.shop_iqns_selected_class();` inside the `cluster` function. During the `new cluster()` call, `this` is the object created by the `new` operator (the one that ends up in `c` in my example above).

Comment: Yeah, I just got it now, something like `this.initiate_auxiliars();` inside my parent `clusters()` function and inside the `initiate_auxiliars()` I run auxiliar functions I need to run without having to instantiate them. Of course, `this.initiate_auxiliars()` will be inside another declared property of the `clusters()` parent function. Thanks for the help and tips :)

Comment: @Roland: No worries, have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `this` all throughout the code. Methods like `$.each` give you another reference:

```
$(".foo").each(function(index, element){
  /* 'element' is better to use than 'this'
     from here on out. Don't overwrite it. */
});
```

Additionally, `$.on` provides the same via the event object:

```
$(".foo").on("click", function(event) {
  /* 'event.target' is better to use than
     'this' from here on out. */
});
```

When your nesting runs deep, there's far too much ambiguity to use `this`. Of course another method you'll find in active use is to create an alias of `that`, which is equal to `this`, directly inside a callback:

```
$(".foo").on("click", function(){
  var that = this;
  /* You can now refer to `that` as you nest,
     but be sure not to write over that var. */
});
```

I prefer using the values provided by jQuery in the arguments, or the event object.